# Beatifulsoup: how to get image size by url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get width and height if the extracted image url, i used `get('width')`, but this seems not working

```
description = soup.find("div", id="module_product_detail")
img= description.find("img")
print(img.get('width'))
```

The output is none.
link looks like this

```
<img alt="image" src="https://bos1.lightake.net:20011/UploadFiles/ShopSkus/1000x1000/Y2463/Y246302/sku_Y246302_1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: you don't have `width` atribute in `img` tag

Comment: is there any way to get width and height by having only url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there's not width nor height attribute, the only way to access the METADATA of the image is by downloading it and reading it like this:

```
from requests import get
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


image_raw = get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png')
image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_raw.content))
width, height = image.size

print(width, height)

# Output:
# 1368 469
```

Comment: `get is not defined`, should i install something else except Pillow module?

Comment: `get` is from `requests` did you import `from requests import get` ?

Comment: You also need to install the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: i already have imported whole requests module, and used before in the script to retrieve urls

Comment: Okay, you can then also `import requests` and then do `requests.get()` if you prefer :-)

Comment: The image you are trying to download can't be found, that's why I went with the Google logo in the example.

Comment: oh you right didn't noticed that one of the image url is not loading, thanks a lot