# How to open the file on internet and check the size

Tags: python, django

I want to open the url such as `https://example.com/test.jpg`

and check the size of image.

My idea is using `subprocess with curl`?

However,I suspect.. it looks not good

Is there any practice for this purpose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116907/beatifulsoup-how-to-get-image-size-by-url

Comment: https://pytutorial.com/getting-image-size-from-url-using-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request

url  = "https://example.com/test.jpg"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
size = len(data)/1024
print(str(size) + " KB")
```